# How can I select two similar field from two similar table?

Tags: sql, ms-access

i have table a with field code and table b with field code
i need

```
a.code   b.code
------   ------
1        4           
2        5          
6        8
```

table a

```
code
----
1
2
6
```

table b

```
code
----
4
5
8
```

How to do that with a single query?

Comment: please, give an example of what you need

Comment: Which sql? SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, Access?

Comment: you need to introduce a sequence number ordering by the code field value ascending and then join on those sequence numbers

Comment: i work with access query

Answer (score 2):

Use `Row_number` plus `CTE`. Try this.

```
;WITH cte1
     AS (SELECT Row_number()OVER(ORDER BY Code) rn,
                Code
         FROM   table1),
     cte2
     AS (SELECT Row_number()OVER(ORDER BY Code) rn,
                Code
         FROM   table2)
SELECT a.Code,
       b.Code
FROM   cte1 a
       JOIN cte2 b
         ON a.rn = b.rn
```

or

```
SELECT a.code,
       b.code
FROM   (SELECT Row_number()OVER(ORDER BY code) rn,
               code
        FROM   table1) a
       INNER JOIN (SELECT Row_number()OVER(ORDER BY code) rn,
                          code
                   FROM   table2) b
               ON a.rn = b.rn
```

**Update :** For Ms-Access use `correlated subquery` to do this

```
SELECT a.code,
       b.code
FROM   (SELECT code,
               (SELECT Count(1)
                FROM   tablea s
                WHERE  s.code >= f.code) rn
        FROM   tablea f) a
       INNER JOIN (SELECT (SELECT Count(1)
                           FROM   tableb s
                           WHERE  s.code >= f.code) rn,
                          code
                   FROM   tableb f) b
               ON a.rn = b.rn
```

Comment: Thank a lot for answer but i use ms_access query and this code have error in Row_number()OVER code?